# Adding new section in SXA toolbox

Tags: sxa

The goal is to create a new section in the toolbox. I created a new **Available Renderings** item called Custom, and I've added two new renderings, **News and Author**. 
When I go to the toolbox instead of one new section called Custom with two renderings in it, I get two new sections, named News and Author, each with one rendering of the same name in it. Any ideas?

Comment: I could not get this to work on SXA, even just getting the toolbox section only did not work for me.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment, or if you need help, you could ask a specific question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2031)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Toolbox displays renderings in a way how they are organised in **Renderings** content tree.

**Available Renderings** plays a role of filter only. Those items define which renderings should be added to a toolbox but do not define a way how they are organised.

In your case you've got one of your renderings under `Renderings/../News` folder and one under `Renderings/../Author`

See how all other renderings are organised into folder categories under renderings
[image]

All sections in the toolbox are sorted alphabetically then.

**How to add a new section in SxA toolbox**

To summarise and make things easier for others, here are steps that you need to perform if you want to add an extra section into Toolbox.

1. Create a folder with **Section name** and put your renderings there.
   [image]
2. Add New Available Renderings item and assign your renderings to it (you can use existing one as well as those plays filtering role only)
   [image]
3. Results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok this might help anyone else that gets stuck, you basically need to make sure you add this section to your site:

**goto:** `Site> Presentation > Available Renderings>` (add the section and the applicable renderings)